# Hey, on using the parameters areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(-3.1756, -3.175), i am getting an error: More in the Details below

Tags: java

From the code below, after subtracting, in this case, for the variables **numDiff1** and **numDiff2**, to chop off the whole number, the variable numDiff2 is reduced to  **-0.174999999** which doesn't make sense as it is supposed to be **-0.175**. **There seems to be a Bug in Java**. Please let me know. Thank you. Is there any other alternative for this?

public static boolean areEqualByThreeDecimalPlaces(double numOne, double numTwo){

```
//For the first parameter
int num1 = (int) numOne;
double numDiff1 = numOne - num1; // numDiff1 = -0.1756000000000002
numDiff1*=1000;
int numFin1 = (int)numDiff1;

//Second parameter
int num2 = (int) numTwo;
double numDiff2 = numTwo - num2; numDiff2 = -0.17499999999999982
numDiff2*=1000;
int numFin2 = (int) numDiff2;


if(numFin1 == numFin2){
    return true;
}else{
    return false; //False
}
```

}

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance.

Comment: "There seems to be a Bug in Java" - it's a good idea to always *start* with the expectation that the problem is in your understanding, rather than in software used by hundreds of thousands of developers. In this case, I believe the problem is your understanding of how floating point numbers are represented.

Comment: (Just occasionally the problem will really be in the widely-used software, but if you start with the *expectation* that that's the case, you'll miss the many, many opportunities to correct your own understanding.)